# Why does France public health system seem to have so many problems despite its rather big financing?

Tags: healthcare, france, public-health

According to [this article](https://www.rfi.fr/en/france/20230106-macron-offers-solutions-but-no-magic-cure-for-france-s-stricken-health-system), France public health system problems became so big that French President Emmanuel Macron addressed to France’s health workers about them:

> French President Emmanuel Macron has unveiled his government's plans
> for the health sector, which is struggling with overcrowded hospitals
> and a lack of staff in rural areas. But in a New Year address to
> health workers, he also warned the crisis could deepen in the coming
> years.

[Macrotrends](https://www.macrotrends.net/countries/FRA/france/healthcare-spending) indicates that France has been spending quite a lot of money (> 11% of GDP) in the last years which is comparable with, let's say, [Sweden](https://www.macrotrends.net/countries/SWE/sweden/healthcare-spending).

Macron indicating population aging is a source of the problems, but most of Europe has an aging population:

> (..) warned the situation in France "could get worse regarding medical
> demographics", pointing to France's ageing population which means a
> high number of doctors and nurses are retiring, many without being
> replaced by equally skilled workers.

What are France's specific causes for the national health system crisis that also led [to important medical staff strikes](https://www.rfi.fr/en/france/20221201-fed-up-french-doctors-and-lab-workers-stage-historic-nationwide-strike)? Are they unique to France or do they also exist in other healthcare systems with similar funding?

Comment: The German health care system is currently really struggling to cope, and there is more money in it than the French system. The British one isn't coping any more at all. So before looking in detail into the problems for the French system, I'd suggest to check whether the Swedish one has similar difficulties.

Comment: *but most of Europe has an aging population* => what makes you believe other countries aren't under strain as well?

Comment: The first context question already mentioned is whether France is actually doing much worse than comparable European countries. The other context question is how much of a problem there actually is? How does the public health system in France today compare to either the system in France 5, 10 or 20 years ago or how does it compare to health care systems in other parts of the world that are designed differently then in Western Europe.

Comment: @paulj Well, fiscally, I'd take the 11% GDP w universal coverage of France's Ponzi scheme way over the US's 18% GDP non-Ponzi.  But that's just my naive and overly cost-focussed self, I am sure.

Comment: Traditionally, France was not very good at controlling what it paid for:  homeopathy only recently got junked, [Thalassotherapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalassotherapy) is [still a thing](https://www.ameli.fr/assure/remboursements/rembourse/cure-thermale).   Last, I figure end of life care swallows as much $ as one cares to throw at it, which happens with most collective medical coverage.  i.e. not a bad Q, but keep in mind most Western countries struggle with similar issues.  Canada sure as heck does.

Comment: [World Bank data up to 2018](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SH.XPD.CHEX.GD.ZS?locations=FR-SE-US-GB-CH).  France is not that unusual.  Guess who stands out.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am sure they do, but things in France seem to be more visible (e.g. MDs protesting, the President speaking about the issue). So, at least it seems to be more serious than it is in similar countries (similar system, about the same financing).

Comment: I do not think it is specific to France. It is difficult to get a properly working health system.

Comment: @Alexei [Slovenia](https://sloveniatimes.com/doctors-strike-averted-as-rallies-in-support-of-public-healthcare-held/), [UK](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-63946730), [Spain](https://www.dw.com/en/hundreds-of-thousands-protest-state-of-madrids-healthcare/a-63743669), and that is just the ones I found. Germany's healthcare system is also in crisis, although it hasn't reached the level of wide-spread protests yet.

Comment: "spending quite a lot of money (> 11% of GDP)" That is pretty average, isn't it? Maybe it only seems to have problems, but doesn't have more problems than others really. "is struggling with overcrowded hospitals and a lack of staff in rural areas" This is just a common place observation. Who is not struggling with that? The question could quantify the alleged problem more.

Comment: [Sweden](https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2022/07/28/a-two-tier-healthcare-system-emerges-in-sweden_5991806_4.html) is also having problems with more people turning to private medicine, according to *Le Monde*. That said, it seems on-topic to ask what are the particular issues affecting French healthcare - nobody would complain about a question about the US healthcare system. Maybe edit the question though.